# Testing for repeated characters in a string

Tags: c#, algorithm, string

I'm doing some work with strings, and I have a scenario where I need to determine if a string (usually a small one < 10 characters) contains repeated characters.

```
`ABCDE`  // does not contain repeats 
`AABCD`  // does contain repeats, ie A is repeated
```

I can loop through the string.ToCharArray() and test each character against every other character in the char[], but I feel like I am missing something obvious.... maybe I just need coffee. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

The string will be sorted, so order is not important so  ABCDA => AABCD

The frequency of repeats is also important, so I need to know if the repeat is pair or triplet etc.

Comment: Would "ABCDA" be treated as having a repeat? I.e. are you interested in any repeats or just consecutive characters?

Comment: What version of the framework?

Comment: Framework version is 3.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the string is short, then just looping and testing may well be the simplest and most efficient way. I mean you *could* create a hash set (in whatever platform you're using) and iterate through the characters, failing if the character is already in the set and adding it to the set otherwise - but that's only likely to provide any benefit when the strings are longer.

EDIT: Now that we know it's sorted, [mquander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829537/testing-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string/829552#829552) is the best one IMO. Here's an implementation:

```
public static bool IsSortedNoRepeats(string text)
{
    if (text.Length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    char current = text[0];
    for (int i=1; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        char next = text[i];
        if (next <= current)
        {
            return false;
        }
        current = next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

A shorter alternative if you don't mind repeating the indexer use:

```
public static bool IsSortedNoRepeats(string text)
{
    for (int i=1; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] <= text[i-1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: Okay, with the "frequency" side, I'll turn the problem round a bit. I'm still going to assume that the string is sorted, so what we want to know is the length of the longest run. When there are no repeats, the longest run length will be 0 (for an empty string) or 1 (for a non-empty string). Otherwise, it'll be 2 or more.

First a string-specific version:

```
public static int LongestRun(string text)
{
    if (text.Length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    char current = text[0];
    int currentRun = 1;
    int bestRun = 0;

    for (int i=1; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (current != text[i])
        {
            bestRun = Math.Max(currentRun, bestRun);
            currentRun = 0;
            current = text[i];
        }
        currentRun++;
    }
    // It's possible that the final run is the best one
    return Math.Max(currentRun, bestRun);
}
```

Now we can also do this as a general extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static int LongestRun(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    bool first = true;
    T current = default(T);
    int currentRun = 0;
    int bestRun = 0;

    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        if (first || !EqualityComparer<T>.Default(element, current))
        {
            first = false;
            bestRun = Math.Max(currentRun, bestRun);
            currentRun = 0;
            current = element;
        }
    }
    // It's possible that the final run is the best one
    return Math.Max(currentRun, bestRun);
}
```

Then you can call `"AABCD".LongestRun()` for example.

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it. +1

Comment: And I thought you were a LINQ evangelist :P

Comment: I'm a fan of LINQ where it's appropriate. In this case, I don't think it is.

Comment: I haven't delved into the MSIL to check, but my assumption was that the compiler would optimize the LINQ to similar as the loop.  Can you elaborate on why you think this is more appropriate?  I think your opinion on that would be very useful.

Comment: Hadn't spotted the frequency bit. Will edit when I have time.

Comment: @balabaster: LINQ will create a hash set (or something similar) behind the scenes, create iterators and all kinds of things which are appropriate for large data sets, but have a relatively high "constant cost" associated with them. I had assumed that the OP wanted an efficient solution.

Comment: @JS Thanks. What you're saying, if I understand you correctly is that my assumption that the compiler would optimize to a similar loop was incorrect, which is fair enough. I hadn't had time to delve into the MSIL to figure that out.

Comment: @balabaster: The C# *compiler* doesn't really have much to do with LINQ unless you're using a query expression. It's the implementation of Distinct() which is important here.

Comment: @JS Gotcha, I'll have a dig into the MSIL to figure out the underlying differences when I get a moment.

Answer (score 18):

If the string is sorted, you could just remember each character in turn and check to make sure the next character is never identical to the last character.

Other than that, for strings under ten characters, just testing each character against all the rest is probably as fast or faster than most other things.  A bit vector, as suggested by another commenter, may be faster (helps if you have a small set of legal characters.)

Bonus:  here's a slick LINQ solution to implement Jon's functionality:

```
int longestRun =
    s.Select((c, i) => s.Substring(i).TakeWhile(x => x == c).Count()).Max();
```

So, OK, it's not very fast! You got a problem with that?!

:-)

Comment: Not very elegant though... a nice little LINQ statement would do it very succinctly.

Comment: That's true, but if he's even asking this question, I assume performance is important.

Answer (score 9):

This will tell you very quickly *if* a string contains duplicates:

```
bool containsDups = "ABCDEA".Length != s.Distinct().Count();
```

It just checks the number of distinct characters against the original length.  If they're different, you've got duplicates...

**Edit:** I guess this doesn't take care of the frequency of dups you noted in your edit though... but some other suggestions here already take care of that, so I won't post the code as I note a number of them already give you a reasonably elegant solution.  I particularly like Joe's implementation using LINQ extensions.

Comment: You can remove the .ToCharArray(), it'll work just fine with only s.Distinct().Count()...

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using 3.5, you could do this in one LINQ query:

```
var results = stringInput
  .ToCharArray() // not actually needed, I've left it here to show what's actually happening
  .GroupBy(c=>c)
  .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
  .Select(g=>new {Letter=g.First(),Count=g.Count()})
;
```

For each character that appears more than once in the input, this will give you the character and the count of occurances.

Comment: You could condense this a lot more by just checking distincts...if there's a different number of distincts than actual, then you've got a duplicate.

Comment: The OP wanted to know which letters were repeated, as well as the number of occurrences, hence my solution above.

Comment: @Bob as noted in the OPs edit, this takes care of the frequency which a more condensed solution probably wouldn't.

Comment: +1 nice solution, as I noted in mine, so long as you don't need frequencies, it becomes even simpler.

Comment: although it works for this solution, you should be selecting g.Key, not g.First()

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way to achieve that is to use this simple regex

```
bool foundMatch = false;
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(yourString, @"(\w)\1");
```

If you need more information about the match (start, length etc)

```
        Match match = null;
    string testString = "ABCDE AABCD";
    match = Regex.Match(testString, @"(\w)\1+?");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string matchText = match.Value; // AA
        int matchIndnex = match.Index;  // 6
        int matchLength = match.Length; // 2
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update** Now, you'd need an array of counters to maintain a count.

Keep a bit array, with one bit representing a unique character. Turn the bit on when you encounter a character, and run over the string once. A mapping of the bit array index and the character set is upto you to decide. Break if you see that a particular bit is on already.

Comment: +1. HashSet is also valid, but since this problem is limited to 26 items a bit / bool array is going to be way faster.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could someone please provide an implementation of this?

Comment: The question has now been edited and this answer no longer works, as it is not possible to get the frequency of duplicates this way.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
string strString = "AA BRA KA DABRA";

var grp = from c in strString.ToCharArray() 
        group c by c into m
        select new { Key = m.Key, Count = m.Count() };

foreach (var item in grp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("Character:{0} Appears {1} times", 
        item.Key.ToString(), item.Count));
}
```

Comment: same as Joe's, but +1 showing different syntax. btw String implements IEnumerable<char>, no need for ToCharArray()

Answer (score 2):

```
/(.).*\1/
```

(or whatever the equivalent is in your regex library's syntax)

Not the most efficient, since it will probably backtrack to every character in the string and then scan forward again. And I don't usually advocate regular expressions. But if you want brevity...

Answer (score 1):

I started looking for some info on the net and I got to the following solution.

```
string input = "aaaaabbcbbbcccddefgg";
        char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
        Dictionary<char, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>();

        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                dictionary[c] = 1; //
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[c]++;
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> combo in dictionary)
        {
            if (combo.Value > 1) //If the vale of the key is greater than 1 it means the letter is repeated
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Letter " + combo.Key + " " + "is repeated " + combo.Value.ToString() + " times");
            }

        }
```

I hope it helps, I had a job interview in which the interviewer asked me to solve this and I understand it is a common question.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no order to work on you could use a dictionary to keep the counts:

```
String input = "AABCD";
var result = new Dictionary<Char, int>(26);
var chars = input.ToCharArray();
foreach (var c in chars)
{
    if (!result.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        result[c] = 0; // initialize the counter in the result
    }
    result[c]++;
}

foreach (var charCombo in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",charCombo.Key, charCombo.Value);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash solution Jon was describing is probably the best.  You could use a HybridDictionary since that works well with small and large data sets.  Where the letter is the key and the value is the frequency.  (Update the frequency every time the add fails or the HybridDictionary returns true for .Contains(key))