# How to check if a string is made of repeating of the same characters?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I am working on log in for my program. I am trying to prevent the user to enter a string of repeating characters such as: `111111` or `aaaaaa`.

How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829537/testing-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = ...
bool notAllSame = input.Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
string str = ...
bool isValid = str.Distinct().Count() > 1;
```

Comment: Do I need to add any namespace for this? It doesn't work as: 'txtPassword.Text.Distinct().Count() > 1'.

Comment: Add the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Yes, you need the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

this function will tell you if you have duplicates. it checks the number of distinct characters against the original length. If they're different, you've got duplicates...

```
bool containsDups = "ABCDEA".Length != s.Distinct().Count();
```

greets,
Stefan

*Edit*

Found your answer here:
[Testing for repeated characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829537/testing-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string)