# Newbie: needs to read file and get frequency of chars

Tags: c#

I have just started learning C#, and came across a problem none of my books can tell me how to resolve.

I want to read a text file and want to put it in an bytearray (`BinaryReader`?) and determine the freqeuncy of all bytes [0..255].

[image: Image of application]

UPDATE:

Well this gets me the desired result:

```
        byte[] bar = File.ReadAllBytes("a.txt");
        long[] far = new long[256];

        foreach (byte b in bar)
        {                
            ++far[b];
        }
```

Thanxs for all the help and effort guys, I really appreciate it;)

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: For the upvoter: _"**This question shows research effort;** it is useful and clear."_

Comment: So you have issues with reading a file? Or with grouping bytes?

Comment: Check out Winston Smiths answer to count frequency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829537/testing-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string

Comment: A simple solution goes something like `uint[] frequencies = new uint[0x100]; foreach (var b in System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)) { frequencies[b]++; }`

Comment: @Brian: I'd like to give the community a bit more credit than that...

Answer (score 6):

> I want to read a text file and want to put it in an bytearray (BinaryReader?) and determine the freqeuncy of all bytes [0..255].

1. Read a text file into bytes: [System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)
2. Loop through each byte with a [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) loop
3. Increment an integer in a suitable data structure representing each byte found

Bonus points and gotchas for:

1. Dealing with large (1GB) files without reading it entirely into memory (hint: check out System.IO.Stream namespace)
2. Unicode (hint: not all languages have 1 byte per character. Check out System.Text namespace)

Comment: +1 for not giving him the codez!

Comment: -1 for not giving any code

Comment: Why talking about unicode? It's not about chars, the OP is interested in **bytes**, so unicode or not doesn't matter.

Comment: I think it's not a "him". ;)

Comment: We don't know for sure if the data in the file represent text, so gotcha `2.` may or may not be relevant.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Text or not, how does it matter? It's about bytes, from 0 to 255, it could represent anything. Unicode or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - me thinks thou doth protest too much. The OP states "I want to read a text file" note the operative word "text". =)

Comment: @ken2k - Depends. A literal interpretation may be indeed that the OP is interested in bytes, and doesn't particularly care how the text is encoded (even though that'd affect the bytes as well). My tingling spidey-sense, however, tells me it much more likely the OP actually wants char counts and is using the old byte==ASCII char shortcut. I could be mistaken, however, which is why it's a gotcha. It needs to be thought about one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most efficient way

```
int b;
var stats = new int[255];
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"file path"))
{
    while(-1 != (b = fs.ReadByte()))
        stats[b]++;
}
```

Comment: I think reading file by chunks (e.g. 1KB) is way more efficient.

Comment: @ken2k if you take a look at `FileStream.ReadByte()` source it already does that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to read *ALL* the bytes from a file is this:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("MyFileName");
```

See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx

I assume that the text file you are reading is ASCII or ANSI? Because if it isn't, you can't just read it as bytes because some of the characters may not be 1 byte long.

Anyway, after you have the byte data array, you can iterate through it to determine the total number of occurrences of each byte:

```
int[] totals = new int[256];

foreach (byte b in data)
{
    ++totals[b];
}
```

Note: This will fail if any byte occurs more than 2^31 times. I'm guessing it won't happen. ;)

I'm not sure what you mean by "frequency". Can you define it?

Comment: "get frequency of chars"

Comment: @SteveMayne In all fairness the content of the question says bytes - slightly confusing.

Comment: @DanielKelley Bytes or chars, the OP is still after the frequency, not just the array.  "Determine the freqeuncy of all bytes [0..255]."

Comment: Woow many thanxs you all!:) i'm gonna try: Ilia G, Cédric Bignon, Sam Shiles, Matthew Watson code now. I will keep you updated!

Comment: Go UInt to double up with the same space

Comment: Well i tried this one first and it seems to be working, gets the bytes of abcde

http://i45.tinypic.com/2nquqhi.png

Now i am trying to get the frequency (number of occurrence) of each byte.

Thanxs aigen for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("file.txt");

        var groups = bytes.GroupBy(x => x);

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", group.Key, group.Count()));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the challenge, in LINQ:

```
byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(myFileName);

var groups = (from character in content 
              group character by character).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => (float)g.Count() / content.Length);
float[] stats = (from character in Enumerable.Range(0, 255)
                 select groups[character]).ToArray();
```

I don't find easier way to do it in LINQ.