# how to check if string has more than two repeating characters

Tags: c#, string, duplicates

I'm trying to check if a string contains more than two repeating characters.

for example

```
'aabcd123' = ok
'aaabcd123' = not ok
'aabbab11!@' = ok
'aabbbac123!' = not ok
```

I've tried something like this but with no luck

```
if (string.Distinct().Count() > 2){ 
                    //do something
                }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does 'no luck' mean?  What is the `if` statement returning?  Have you looked into using a [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to accomplish this?

Comment: [Also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829537/testing-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string)...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829537/testing-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string

Comment: why is `'aaabcd123'` not OK? It **does** contain more than two repeating characters.

Comment: Distinct() returns a collection with the distinct elements in the original collection, and Count() just counts that. That's why you have no luck with that statement.

Comment: @Michael_B I don't think that post applies, because he appears to be talking about characters repeated consecutively (which is why 'aabbab11!@' is ok, but 'aabbbac123!' is not

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer what you're looking for.  To me it looks like you're looking for strings where substrings of adjacent repeated characters within the original string are no longer than 2 characters.  Is that correct?  (I choose this because it matches your input samples...but it's not obvious from your description that's what you're after.)

Comment: Anyone know why my question was down pointed? advice on what I need to include in the question when down pointing would be appreciated for future questions. thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
public bool  IsOK(string s)
{
  if(s.Length < 3) return true;

  return !s.Where((c,i)=> i >= 2 && s[i-1] == c && s[i-2] == c).Any();
}

'aabcd123'     : OK
'aaabcd123'    : not OK
'aabbab11!@'   : OK
'aabbbac123!'  : not OK
```

Comment: this is perfect. Can be done to be more performant, like avoiding linq?

Comment: Why do you think Linq hurts performance here? Yes you could change it to a direct `while` loop, or a `foreach` with a break condition, but I don't think it will help much.

Comment: No, you are right. I already did it and no change. I thought it because the "Where", I try to avoid linQ (Im doing this code as 15k /s times)

Comment: The key is that `Any` will stop asking the `Where` for matches as soon as it finds a match, so it's only filtering the entire collection if there is _no_ match.

Answer (score 8):

Just for classic loops sake:

```
public bool HasRepeatingChars(string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.Length - 2; i++)
        if(str[i] == str[i+1] && str[i] == str[i+2])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex for this one:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"(.)\1{2,}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This checks for any character, then for at least 2 times that same character. Works even with strings like "AaA" and can be modified to find out exactly what those characters are, where they are occurring in the string, and much more (also allows you to replace those substrings with something else)

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to find runs of three characters and not just three characters in a string, you need to loop through and look at three consecutive characters to see if they are the same.  A loop like this will work.

```
string myString = "aaabbcd";
bool hasMoreThanTwoRepeatingCharsInARow = false;
for(int index = 2; index < myString.Length; index++)
{
  if(myString[index] == myString[index - 1] && myString[index] == myString[index - 2])
  {
    hasMoreThanTwoRepeatingCharsInARow = true;
  }
}
```

I would stick this in a method and make the variables better and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        const string sample1 = "aabcd123";
        const string sample2 = "aaabcd123";
        const string sample3 = "aabbab11!@";
        const string sample4 = "aabbbac123!";

        Assert.IsTrue(IsOk(sample1));
        Assert.IsFalse(IsOk(sample2));
        Assert.IsTrue(IsOk(sample3));
        Assert.IsFalse(IsOk(sample4));
    }

    private bool IsOk(string str)
    {
        char? last = null;
        var i = 1;
        foreach (var c in str)
        {
            if (last == c)
            {
                i++;
                if (i > 2) return false;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 1;
            }
            last = c;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex

```
(?:.*<letter>.*){2}
```

For letter b for example you'd use

```
(?:.*b.*){2}
```

For all vowels

```
 (?:.*[aeiou].*){2}
```

For regex usage on c# refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0